# Will a PHP 301 redirect use bandwidth?

Tags: php, redirect, http-status-code-301, bandwidth

I need to redirect streams for a project. I am thinking it will be a cheap way to obfuscate their location and therefore protect them.

Although, I have a question about it.

The streams are on another server but will they also use bandwidth on the server I am going to use this PHP?

```
 <?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://hls.adaptive.examplelevel99.net/folder/channel/vid54231.m3u8");
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would require very little bandwidth however if you must save the bandwidth try redirecting from apache, CPU and bandwidth usage on redirects is minimal especially if you're doing them with Apache directly

Comment: Little because it only loads the PHP? Or little as it is streaming the video through this server but that wont use much? I have potentially several dozen video feeds I need to redirect like this. Each will have multiple people consuming the streams.

Comment: if I understand it correctly you have php page A, and a video page B, when you redirect A->B, the browser will request data from B( A will be used only once during the redirection )

Comment: Yes but will that be the bandwidth of the streams going through the server with PHP or is the only bandwidth from actually loading the PHP page in the first place? Please.

Comment: Only bandwidth from actually loading the PHP page in the first place

Comment: That is ace thanks. OD you know if it will be masked properly or will the original URL still show if somebody was to sniff using a tool?

Comment: I would not count on it , it is far too easy to locate these urls using simple browser tools, if you really want to protect the urls, you may have to use different security methods